# How to edit the contents of a window from another window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, pointers, reference

In my program I have two windows, the first one being my main window with a text box and the second one having an entry field with a button to update the text box in the first window. I'm a beginner in terms of using WPF and coding in C# in general, but is there a way to pass a pointer or reference of my main window to the second window so the second window can edit the text box of my first window? Is that even the right way to think about solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

WPF assumes you are binding your forms to a ViewModel object. This object can be bound to more than one form to give you different views and capabilities, so in this case you'd bind the same ViewModel to both forms, and what is changed in your edit form will appear automatically in your main form.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague and there are many approaches to accomplishing this.  MVVM as Steve Todd mentions, is one.

However, it sounds like you simply want to open the window as a dialog.  In your second window's code behind, be sure your textbox has a name in XAML and then access it create and easily accessible property that gets and sets your textbox value.

```cs
public MyTextContent 
{
 get => this.MyTextBox.Text; 
 set => this.MyTextBox.Text = value;
}
```

You can control the return value based on conditions (such as OK or Cancel buttons) if you like by using click events.  The window contains a DialogResult property.  The default is false, so you will need to set this somewhere.

```
this.DialogResult = true; // OK
```

Then in your main window's code behind, create a new instance of the window, assign it's property and show it.  This will need to be done during a click event of a button or some similar trigger

```cs
var myDialog = new MyDialogWindow()
{
  MyTextContent = "Textbox Starting Value";
}

bool? result = myDialog.ShowDialog(); // Returns when the dialog window is closed.
if(result != null && result)
{
  this.LocalTextBox.Text = myDialog.MyTextContent; // Copy the text to the main textbox.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do this in data context of your main window. You use IoC to pass an instance of popup notification service in the constructor and create a private reference. You call that service method that displays the popup notification where user can enter async (and await) for its response or use reactive extensions to subscribe to submit action of that button. A thing to look out for is that you can update ui only in dispatcher thread and do not forget to dispose the subscription after you have finished using the window.